# What Cloud Service should I use to deploy mobile apps and when should I use Cloud Services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, native, amazon-mobile-hub

Should I use Amazon Web Services Mobile, Google Cloud Mobile, or deploy on app store. This is a social media app that is going to be native to iOS first and eventually will be released to Android. It allows users to take pictures, and send messages.

Comment: Your post shouldn't really have the iOS tag, since the **only** answer for non-jailbroken iOS devices is the Apple App store.

Answer (score 0):

Well I suggest to go the native way and submit it to the App Store. It makes the easiest way for the wide majority of users to download the app and provide better visibility.

There are 2 ways to spread your app to clients. Either submitting it to the app store where it get public and anyone can download, or you send them the Application by email via tools like installr. However the first option is the much recommended option

Hope this helps!

Comment: What's the difference between just submitting to the app store and deploying it with a cloud service?